# DB Table Design Structure for Sepeartion based on Type

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a Different Real Estate Projects Listed In My website.

The Projects are separated as below.

```
affordable
budget segment 
Luxurious  
affordable & budget segment 
budget segment & Luxurious  
affordable,budget segment &  Luxurious.
```

I will use the above classification to populate in the similar projects tab in the Project Description page.

For Eg

```
ProjectName          Class
ProjectA           Affordable
ProjectB           Budget Segment
ProjectC           Affordable & Budget Segment
ProjectD           Budget Segment               
ProjectE           Affordable
ProjectF           Affordable, Budget Segment &  Luxurious
```

Now in the Project Description page for ProjectA people should see  ProjectC, ProjectE, ProjectF in Similar Projects Tab Since ProjectA is Affordable and ProjectC, ProjectE, ProjectF contains houses under Affordable Segment.

Suggest me a Single Column table Structure to the above Requirement and a query to get Similar Projects.

Thank You

Comment: A solution  single column table structure is over constraining the problem. This problem is best solved with a 1 many relationship. Otherwise you end up with a total hack.

Comment: If this isn't homework then why are you constraining answers to a single-column-table structure? If it is homework, why haven't you tagged it thus?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the comment above that you should use a 1-to-many relationship. If you *must* have it as only one column then:

Assign an int value to each of these and use **numeric `+` to store** and **bitwise AND (`&`) to retrieve** different combinations.

```
Affordable = 1
Budget Segment = 2
Luxurious = 4         # Note: it's Four, not Three.
```

Notice that `4+2+1=7`. Store it as `proj_val` in the `proj_description` table.

Putting these values in your projects list:

```
ProjectName        Class                            int val
-----------        -----                            -------
ProjectA           Affordable                             1
ProjectB           Budget Segment                         2
ProjectC           Affordable & Budget Segment        1+2=3
ProjectD (=ProjB)  Budget Segment                         2
ProjectE (=ProjA)  Affordable                             1
ProjectF           Affordable, Budget & Luxurious   1+2+4=7
no Proj ?          Luxurious                              4
........           Affordable + Luxurious             1+4=5
........           Budget + Luxurious                 2+4=6
```

To get the Similar for Project A, do:

```
SELECT * FROM `proj_description` WHERE `proj_val` & 1 != 0
```

The `1` is calculated based on table above. So Proj C (`proj_val=3`) would give Proj F as a result: `3 & 7 = 3` which is not zero.